# Linux command to view raw file, including its delimiters

Tags: linux, awk, sed, terminal

I'm trying to view the content of a file including its delimiters in terminal.
For example:

```
hello\t\tworld\n
hello\t\tworld\t\tagain\n
```

instead of just:

```
hello world
hello world again
```

I did this once awhile ago using either "sed" or "awk"....I think...but, I can't seem to remember any of it now.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does `cat -A` (or `cat -vET`) do the job for you?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You should probably make an answer out of it.

Comment: It's not the same format, hence the question.

Comment: I see, it's not the same format, but I can see the delimiters. Thanks guys!

Comment: also, you can use `od -t a file` or `od -t c file`

Comment: Thanks @JoseRicardoBustosM. That's the one that I used to use!!

Answer (score 5):

VI can show you this if open the file in it and type :set list.

e.g.

```
$ cat test.txt
hello           world
hello           world           again
```

In VI the ^I are tabs and $ are Line Feeds.

[image]

Also like the comment states - `cat -A` will get you the same output:

```
$ cat -A test.txt
hello^I^Iworld$
hello^I^Iworld^I^Iagain$
```

Comment: I don't use vi, but the cat -A works fine. It's just a different format. But, works for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `od` command,

```
od -t a input_file | awk '{$1=""}1' | 
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[ \t\n]+";ORS="";
    d["sp"]=" "; d["nl"]="\\n\n"; d["ht"]="\\t"; d["cr"] = "\\r";
}length($0)>1{$0=d[$0]}1'
```

with `input_file`

```
hello       world
hello       world again
```

you get,

```
hello\t\tworld\n
hello\t\tworld again\n
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n l0 file
```

This will show any tabs and newlines will be replaced by `$`.

If you wish to see newlines as `\n` then slurp the whole file:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;$!d;x;l0' file
```

Comment: nice command 

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` should probably work, you can just modify it to match and display whatever it is you want to see (e.g. whitespace). The tricky part is matching newlines since `sed` utilizes newlines to delimit the stream, it is already consumed prior to you getting to it. So matching along the lines of `sed 's/\n/\\n/'` will fail, you can presume the newline by matching the end character and tack on the `\\n`.

`sed 's/$/\\n/;s/\t/\\t/g;s/ \{4\}/\\t/g' file`